# Django pre- and post- signals mocking

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, python-mock

There is preventing of pre- and post-signals in a view for some reasons.

```
def view(*args):
    # disable pre- and post-save signals for MyModel
    my_model_object.save()
    # anable pre- and post-save signals for MyModel
```

How can I mock django pre_save and post_save signals to check that they were not called by MyModel? (There is not any receiver to check if it isn't called)

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
def MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      super(MyTestCase, self).setUp()
      self.patcher = patch('django.db.models.signals.pre_save')
      self.mocked_pre_save = self.patcher.start()

    def test_pre_save_signal_not_sent(self):
      self.admin_post(url, post_data)
      pre_save_senders_list = [arg[1]['sender'] for arg in mocked_pre_save.send.call_args_list]
      self.assertNotIn(MyModel, pre_save_senders_list)
```

Comment: I think you should provide the actual test